# How to load spring application context within submodule

Tags: java, spring, maven

I was writing simple app for data deletion in db with some command line interface. As it got bigger, I decided to split it into two maven submodules (one cli, one for db operations). Everything worked properly with one `applicationContext` loaded within `Main` method.

After change, I left (at least I would like to) the spring only in the db module. This module has one public interface (with four implementations). If it will be included into other project, I do not want to manually load the application context of that db module in other one (not sure if it is even possible). I simply want to have a `jar` which could be used on the go - just add to the pom.xml and that's all. On the other hand I do not know how to initialize this context within submodule. Is it possible, or should I ask, is my pattern a good one?

I know there exists `@ContextConfiguration` annotation, but according to the documentation it is for integration tests.

Comment: There has to be a main application context which loads the others. Do you want your DB JAR to be the top-level context?

Comment: Point is, someone else might use my jar, I'm not sure if there will be spring also, so I may assume that DB Jar might be the top-level context.

Answer (score 0):

You can always import other configuration files into your current module. That way you can group your contexts according to your business need.

```
<beans>
  <import resource="classpath*:root-module-context.xml"/>
  <bean>.. </bean>
</beans>
```